# Voice Actions Activity code not found

Tags: android, voice, google-voice-actions

I'm working with adding Voice Actions to my app. [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/interaction/voice-interactions) tells me to use the method `isVoiceInteraction()` in an activity however every time I run a build (command line or IDE) I get errors saying the method can't be found. My question is, why?

I decompiled the source of an Activity and saw the method is there when I target API 21.

Here's my default build config:

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    // version name and code set here
}
```

The method can be found if I change the compile, min, and target SDK version to `android-MNC` however that isn't what I need.

Why is my build not recognizing the any of the voice methods defined in an Activity (as of Android 5.0+)?

My confusion is that I'm working with a custom voice action. It was approved however I was told (from the Google Voice Actions Team) that I need to have my new APK submitted to the play store by August 7th, 2015. That seems odd because I don't think I can submit an APK targeting the preview SDK.

Comment: My understanding of what I was supposed to do was all wrong. I was confusing "Custom Voice Actions" with "Voice Interactions". As Ian says in his answer the latter is only available in MNC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voice Interactions is one of the features added in [Android M](http://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#voice-interactions) - you'll need to ensure you follow the [Preview SDK](http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html#update) instructions and compile and target `"android-MNC"`